# Unused parameters and control reaches end of non-void function errors when compiling - CS50 pset3 - music

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

I have tried and googled everything, but I cannot seem to fix these mysterious errors. Within my helpers.c file, it is saying that I haven't used any of the parameters although I've used all of them.

Below are the errors I'm getting:

```
helpers.c:8:21: error: unused parameter 'fraction' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter] int duration(string fraction) ^

helpers.c:11:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type] } ^

helpers.c:14:22: error: unused parameter 'note' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter] int frequency(string note) ^

helpers.c:17:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type] } ^

helpers.c:20:21: error: unused parameter 's' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter] bool is_rest(string s) ^

helpers.c:23:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type] } ^

6 errors generated.
```

Here is my code:

// Helper functions for music

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "helpers.h"

// Converts a fraction formatted as X/Y to eighths
int duration(string fraction)
{
    // convert string input to int
    int x = fraction[0] - '0';
    int y = fraction[2] - '0';
    // convert to integral number of eighths
    if (y == 8)
    {
        return x;
    }
    return (8 / y) * x;
}

// Calculates frequency (in Hz) of a note
int frequency(string note)
{
    // Parse string <note> //not quite sure on data types (chars or int?)
    int baseHz = 440; //A4's Hz
    char letter = note[0];

    if (strlen(note) < 3) //notes with # or b
    {
        int octave = note[1] - '0';
    }
    else //notes without # or b
    {
        int octave = note[2] - '0';
    }
    //find distance from octave 4
    int octave_dist = octive - 4; //power of 2 for octave adjustment
    //multiplier to adjust for octave
    int octave_adjust = pow(2, octave_dist); //not sure on types here??

    //find note distance from A
    float n = 2.0; //number of semitones between notes
    if (letter != 'B') //B will use default n = 2
    {
        n = ('A' - letter) * 2;
    }
    //multiplier to adjust for note
    float note_adjust = pow(2, n/12.0);

    //multiplier to adjust for # or b

    int Hz = round(baseHz * octave_adjust * note_adjust);
    return Hz;
}

// Determines whether a string represents a rest
bool is_rest(string s)
{
    //get_string return "" if user input is only a line ending
    if (strcmp(s, "") == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm still working on my functions (step by step) as recommended by course instructions, but I can't even compile to see if anything I've done is correct.

I don't understand why I haven't "used the parameters" Another thing I can point out is that my errors are giving me the (seemingly) incorrect locations. Could this mean there is something wrong with the IDE/compiler/makefile?

I've been killing myself over this for days. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should probably get a text book and read about *scopes*, and how variables defined inside a nested scope only have a life-time of that scope. Then think about the variable `octave` in the `frequency` function.

Comment: “octive” looks like a typo.

Comment: `int octave_dist = octive - 4;` does the compiler not complain about this? `octive` is not defined in the code you show us.

Comment: More related to your problem, are you sure you're compiling the source file you think you're compiling? Because the line numbers reported in the errors doesn't match anything in the source file you show? And the source file you show have *other* errors that the compiler should complain about. Did you remember to save the file? Is it the correct file you're editing?

Comment: none of the errors listed would be fatal without `-Werror` (that instructs the compiler to threat all warnings as errors). You don't mention what compiler are you using, if it is gcc, you can try the `-E` flag to see the source after the precompiler pass, but looking at the errors looks like there's a mismatch between your sources and what is compiled (for instance `s` is used)

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. The problem was twofold: first, for some reason i wasn't saving the correct file - solved this by using "save as" and manually clicking the helpers.c filw. Second, I fixed the declaration issues with octave (and fixed the octive typo) . All is compiling successfully - thank you so much!